# Leaflet ESRI Dynamic Map Layer

Tags: leaflet, map-service

I am using 'Esri brochure' to load URL ArcGIS tourism services with the API 'L.esri.DynamicMapLayer'.
I'm looking for a way to know how many layers there are in that service, preferably the layer id.

I.e:

this service:
sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hurricanes/MapServer

has two layers

sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hurricanes/MapServer/0
sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hurricanes/MapServer/1